# JS - How to update cookies to samesite none

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am working with a third party js script. The third party script sets cookies, but doesn't set them to `samesite=none` and `secure`. This is problematic because a call is later made to this third party. and i get "Issues" in the chrome developer panel that says `Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute`. It tells me i have 18 cookies that were filtered out of each request because the `sameSite` attribute was defaulted to `Lax`.

Question: Is there anyway to update all cookies under a given domain and set their attribute of sameSite to be None?

Answer (score 1):

If the domain match the domain of the JavaScript origin, you can update your cookies (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/document/cookie)

In javascript to update cookies you can do :

```
document.cookie = your_old_cookie + "; Secure; SameSite=None; path=/";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [cookiejs](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#samesite) and run the below script

```
document.cookie.split(';').map(cookie => {
 const _cookie = cookie.split('=')
 Cookies.set(_cookie[0], _cookie[1], { sameSite: 'none' })
})
```

Note that more recent browsers are making "Lax" the default value even without specifiying anything here.